# Could not find file - "Content-Disposition" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, webclient, content-disposition

I have implemented Web file manager in my application. It shows the files from the FTP server.
When i try to **download the file** by clicking on the file i'm getting the following error.
Getting the error during `WriteFile` line getting executed.

Error:

> *Could not find file 'C:\Users\ ####\Desktop\SeekDotNetFileManager\AdminMaster.master.cs'.*

//Code:

```
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + lnkName.Text.Trim());
  Response.WriteFile(lnkName.Text);
  Response.End();
```

In the `lnkName.Text.Trim` the name of the file will be set.
Eg: AdminMaster.master.cs

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Change the app pool to your user account and try again.

Comment: The error is very straightforward - the file is not there. Double check if it really exists or the AppPool's identity has enough access to the file.

Comment: I'm trying to download the clicked file.

Answer (score 0):

Got a Solution:

//Code

```
            string filename = 'Get the full path of file'; //something like /httpdocs/Images/button.gif
            string strURL = "http://www.servername.com/";

            WebClient req = new WebClient();
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            byte[] data = req.DownloadData(strURL);
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
            response.End();
```